# Is there an API or a simple way to check if a volume is deduped on Windows server 2012?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2012

Here's the MSDN page about [Data deduplication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it seems there's no API to check if a volume is deduped.

One way to do it  is to check if there's a folder named "Dedup" under "System Volume Information", but I don't think it is reliable for every case.

Comment: Using WMI (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769311(v=vs.85).aspx), you can check if dedup is enabled for a volume (using the Enabled property)

Comment: This should work. I want to know if there's windows API for it, simpler than the WMI solution

Comment: WMI is the API that Windows provides for this kind of operation. You can use WMI interfaces inside your C++ application and use its properties.

Comment: It seems to be only way to do that: using WMI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of deduped volumes can be obtained in powershell. See the following link about a third of the way down the page

http://windows-scripting.org/category/windows-2012/

Comment: I think the powershell script is using WMI too.

Comment: Wmi is the only way you are going to be able to get the information. Why is that an issue?

Comment: Just wonder if there an windows API for this, called by C/C++